# converting 220v ac sognal to 5v or 3.3v signal

Tags: mains, level-shifting

i need to convert 220v signal to 5v or 3.3 v signal if push button pressed..

i tried the following circuts:

1)using neon lamp and ldr:

[image]

**this circuit works fine and do what i need but if push button has indication lamp across it it doesn't work as neon lamp alwyas on.

[image]

so i decide to go through second circuit.

2-)using 220v coil relay :

[image]

this circuit also works fine but as in circuit 1 ih i used push button has indication neon lamp across it the relay stay always on.

so i decide to go to 3rd circuit

3-)using optocoupler

[image]

this circuit not tested because i dont know the type and rated power of R2 and type of C1.

my question if i use this circuit i will face the same problem as in circuits 2 & 2 ?

if yes how can i solve this problem.

regards

Comment: can you elaborate; is your indication lamp is in parallel with your push button?

Comment: Are you requiring an indicator lamp showing that 220 VAC is available, regardless of the push button?

Comment: @navaro yes :)


_____________________

Comment: @jonk there are 20 push buttons in our staircase all of them has indication lamp.

Comment: @vtc Each of the 20 indication lamps are always-on, regardless of the state of any one or more push-button(s)? You didn't actually answer that question, as I read you. (Sorry to ask, but these are questions that come to mind and some of us would rather not make assumptions. A ***direct*** and ***detailed*** answer would help. [Writing "too much" is almost always better.])

Comment: @jonk when any of buttons pressed the indication lamps become off

Comment: @jonk I think the OP is talking about typical doorbell knob that has neon lamp in parallel with the button. It is always on (to make knob visible at night) but goes off when button pressed. We have exactly same button at our front door.

Comment: @Maple 20 of these on a stairway? All arranged so that any of them being pressed causes all of them to go off. Hmm. Okay. I would NEVER have been able to guess that.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What else is the button connected to? How are the line (hot) and neutral connected to the button and the "else" stuff?

Comment: @Maple Are you sure your doorbell doesn't have a low-voltage incandescent or LED for illumination? All of the doorbells I've owned used a low voltage, typically 24V, which would not illuminate a neon bulb.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Hmm... could be. The only time I opened it I saw something that looks like neon bulb and a resistor inside. The resistor made me think it is neon. Did not pay much attention though. But it is wired in parallel to the button, at least that much I am sure about.

Comment: @jonk all buttons are connected in parallel . and yes when any of buttons pressed all indication lamps off.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson what i need is to convert 220v signal when push button pressed to a signal can i fed it to any microcontroller.

i tested the circuit 1 and 2 in my workbench with one push button and this button doesn't have indication lamp hence the circuit do what i need.

but when i try to connect push buttons which have indication neon lamp across them the circuit doesn't work .

Comment: @vts, what you _really_ need is to convert 0V signal when push button pressed.

Comment: But you **don't** have a 220V signal. You have some switches, some neon bulbs, and something else connected to all of the switches. If you refuse to give us the whole picture it will be difficult to give you a useful answer.

Comment: @Maple no its look at circuit one it includes neon lamp in series with push button.

i have two cases:
1. if push button doesn't have indication lamp :when i press the button the neon bulb become on and the ldr sensing the light and a logic 1 signal will fed to MCU when button noy pressed the neon lamp will be off so no light sensing by ldr and logic zero fed to mcu.

case #2 if the button has indication led across it:
in this case the neon lamp always on even the button not pressed so the ldr always sens the light and mcu always see logic 1.

Comment: What do you mean you have two cases? There is only one case: a combination of how you want your circuit to behave, what parts you have available and how (if at all) they already wired. I agree with @ElliotAlderson, it is time for you to either give whole picture or stop wasting people's time. The circuits in your question (the ones you call "cases") obviously did not work for you, so they are truly irrelevant.

Comment: @maple i modified the post include picture..
may describe what the two cases ..

the terminal denoted as input will be connected to MCU input pin.

regards

Comment: @vtc You keep including _solutions_ while questioned about _requirements_. Sorry, I am giving up. Hopefully others will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the circuit holds a 220VAC relay closed it is passing a fair bit of current. A typical small relay coil might be 30K or so. The neon probably has 50-100K in series for a high brightness short life bulb @240VAC.

You can probably use any of those circuits if you parallel the input with a relatively low value resistor or a small incandescent lamp.

For the relay, try 10K 10W wirewound. It will get hot if the switch is held down (or shorted).

Edit:
I see from your comments you have *many* switches connected in parallel. So you may have to use a lower resistance resistor (which means more watts). Or use an incandescent bulb if you can find one.

Comment: Since OP indicated that all buttons have neons in parallel and all buttons wired in parallel as well, what is basically needed is a circuit that detects _zero_ voltage across.

Comment: you said if i parallel the input .. which input you mean ?

Comment: Across the coil in the case of the relay.

Comment: @Maple That's certainly a possibility to detect the presence or lack of current near (not at) the zero crossing- you want to propose a design in an answer?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Not really. First, you already started an answer, so you can simply add that option. And second, at this point I am not sure if what I said about wiring was correct. Need something definite from OP first.

Comment: if i used ldr method how can i determine the resistor value ?

also if there is another circuits will do what i need ?

Comment: @vtc You could do it experimentally, Or put a [40W 240VAC bulb](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/vQcAAOSwepJXZj1H/s-l1600.jpg) across where you marked L/N.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany 
thank you for your appreciated effort..

i used resistor it solved my problem :)
also i used 40W 240VAC bulb and solved the problem :)

can i use capacitor instead of parallel resistor ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the neon bulbs in the buttons to stay on you can add a shunt resistor in parallel with the relay.  This will prevent enough current from flowing through the relay to activate it and allow enough current through both the relay and the shunt to light up the bulbs.  When the button is pressed, then there is enough current available to activate the relay.  Mind you this is not the most efficient method, but it is simple.  You'll have to choose a resistor that will divert enough current from the relay so that it is below the holding current of the relay.

Or if you don't care about the neon bulbs lighting up, you can add a resistor in series with the relay such that the current available from the neon bulbs is less than the holding current of the relay.

Both methods require knowing more about the relay in order to choose a suitable resistor.

Comment: thank you if i add the series resistor .the indication lamp will be on when the button not pressed ?

and you say using the relay not the most efficient method ,could you tell me what is the most efficient method ?

what about circuit 1 ?

Comment: Using the relay is fine for efficiency, it's the adding of the shunt resistor that is not very power efficient.  You can use the same concepts for circuit 1, I'm just not as familiar with neon bulbs.

Comment: thank you for your appreciated effort..
i used resistor it solved my problem :)

can i use capacitor instead of parallel resistor ?

Comment: I would avoid that in this application.  A capacitor in parallel with a coil is what is known as a tank circuit; they oscillate together.